# $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}(f\cdot g)(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, convolution

suppose $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $g$ bounded. then $\lim_\limits{{|x|\to\infty}}(f\cdot g)(x)=0$?

since $|(f\cdot g)(x)|=|\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x-y)\,g(y)\,dy|\leq ||g||_\infty\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x-y)|\,dy=||g||_\infty||f||_1<\infty$,

at least the limit is bounded. I guess I need to know if $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x-y)|\,dy$ goes to $0$ as $|x|\rightarrow \infty$, but I got nothing until now.

if $x$ moves finite distance, then the integral won't change. would it be different near $\infty$?

Comment: in line 2 better replace your expression with $||g||_\infty ||f||_1 < \infty $ otherwise its trivial

Comment: @Simonsays thanks! I edited.

Comment: You should use the fact that both functions are integrable, so you can choose a sufficiently large $R$ so that $\int_{B_R^c}|f|,\int_{B_R^c} |g|\le \epsilon$, then for example you may write $f=f\chi_{B_R}+f\chi_{B_R^c}$, so that you can play with different estimations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convolution is both uniformally continuous and $L^1$.

To see this, note the other answer and, for every $x,h\in \mathbb{R}$ we have

$$|(f*g)(x)-(f*g)(x-h)| = |(f*g)(x)- (f*g)_h(x)| = |(f*g)(x)-(f_h*g)(x)|$$
Next, by lineary we have $(f*g)(x)-(f_h*g)(x) = ((f-f_h)*g )(x)$ and finally

$$|(f*g)(x)-(f*g)(x-h)| \leq \|f-f_h\|_{L^1} \|g\|_{L^\infty}$$ which tends to $0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$. since $x$ was arbitrary, we have uniform convergence and so the tail must decay.

Comment: if a function is just $L^1$, then can the tail of it not decay? I mean, do we need the uniform continuity?

Comment: @user159234 Yes! An $L^1$ function does not necessarily decay to $0$ at the tail. The standard example is rectangles (or triangles, if you want it to be continuous) of ever decreasing width and increasing height: Take $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[n,n+\frac{1}{n^3})}(x)$. It is obvious such function does not decay to $0$, and the integral is just $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} <\infty$

Answer (score 2):

We have 
\begin{align}
(f\ast g)(x)
&= (g\ast f)(x) \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}g(x-y)f(y)dy \\
&= \int_{B_R(x)}g(x-y)f(y)dy + \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_R(x)}g(x-y)f(y)dy \\
&= \int_{B_R(x)}g(x-y)f(y)dy + \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_R(x)}g(x-y)f(y)1_{\{ f\leq k\}}dy +\int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_R(x)}g(x-y)f(y)1_{\{ f > k\}}dy,
\end{align}
where $B_R(x)$ denotes the closed ball with radius $R>0$ and center $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $k>0$ is also arbitrary.

**We can estimate the third term** as
$$\lvert \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_R(x)}g(x-y)f(y)1_{\{ f > k\}}dy\rvert\leq \lVert g \rVert_\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(y)|1_{\{ f > k\}}dy
$$
$f\in L^1$ yields
$$1_{\{ f > k\}}\rightarrow 0,\; k\rightarrow \infty ,$$
and dominated convergence thus implies
$$ 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(y)|1_{\{ f > k\}}dy \rightarrow 0,\; k\rightarrow \infty.$$
Note that this convergence is independent of $x$ and $R$.

**The second term** is much easier to estimate: We write 
\begin{align}
\lvert \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_R(x)}g(x-y)f(y)1_{\{ f\leq k\}}dy \rvert 
&\leq k \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_R(x)}|g(x-y)|dy \\
&= k \int_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus B_R(0)}|g(y)|dy
\end{align}
Letting $R\rightarrow \infty$ yields convergence towards $0$ since $g\in L^1$. Note that this convergence is independent of $x$.

**For the first term we have**, similarily, 
\begin{align}
\lvert \int_{B_R(x)}g(x-y)f(y)dy \rvert 
&\leq \lVert g \rVert_\infty \int_{B_R(x)}|f(y)|dy.
\end{align}
If $R$ is fixed, the RHS converges to $0$ for $|x|\rightarrow \infty$ since $f\in L^1$.

**Now let $\varepsilon >0$**. We first chose $k>0$ such that the third term is smaller than $\frac \varepsilon 3$. Remember that this choice is independent from $R$ and $x$, so we can now chose $R$ sufficiently big for the second term to be smaller than $\frac \varepsilon 3$. Since this choice was also independent of $x$, we can finally chose $x_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the first term is smaller than $\frac \varepsilon 3$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\Vert x \Vert \geq x_\varepsilon$.

Comment: thank you for the great answer. but I'm just curious, can't we just say that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d-B_R(x)}|g(x-y)f(y)|dy\longrightarrow 0$ as $R\longrightarrow \infty$? since $g(x-y)f(y)\in L^1$ as a function of $y$? if we can, then I think we don't need to divide the integral into three parts.

Comment: regarding other answers, I guess we need uniform continuity to conclude $f\in L^1\Longrightarrow\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$... and $f,g$ are not uniformly continuous in general.

Comment: That was what I intended to do, but I think you get the problem here that this $L^1$-function depends on $x$. So you can't chose $R$ before you chose $x$ and vice versa because the choice of $x$ for the first term also depends on $R$.

Comment: If you mean @Ranc 's  answer, he doesn't claim uniform continuity for $f$ or $g$, and he doesn't show $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$. He _shows_ uniform continuity for $f\ast g$ using $f\in L^1$ and boundedness of $g$. You have already shown in your question that $f\ast g \in L^1$.

Comment: yes, I just pick $f$ as an arbitrary function. I mean, it seems we need both $L^1$ and uniform continuity to show that the tail decays.

Comment: You are confusing the functions we are talking about. We do not show that the tail of $f$ decays and in general it doesn't. We show that the tail of $f\ast g$ decays.That's why we show uniform continuity for $f\ast g$ and **not for f** (which in general is not uniformly continuous). In the proof for the uniform continuity of $f\ast g$, we only use $f\in L^1$ and that $g$ is bounded.

Comment: I was thinking that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d-B_R(x)}|f(y)|dy\to 0$ as $R\to \infty$ or $|x|\to \infty$, and $\lim_{|x|\to 0}f(x)=0$ are the same thing but it wasn't. that's why I was confused I guess.

Comment: and, about the dependence of $R$ and $x$, how about $\int |g(x-y)f(y)|dy\leq ||g||_\infty\int|f(y)|dy$? since $f(y)$ does not depend on $x$, we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(y)|dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d-B_R(x)}|f(y)|dy+\int_{B_R(x)}|f(y)|dy$, so the graph of $f$ is fixed, we can safely move and raise the ball?

Comment: Note that $\int_{B_R(x)} |f(y)|dy\rightarrow \Vert f \Vert_{L^1}, \ R\rightarrow \infty$, but we need convergence towards 0.

Answer (score 1):

here is my idea: note that for summable $f,g$ the following equations holds: 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d}|f*g| \space dx = \bigg(\int_{\mathbb R^d}|f| dx\bigg)\bigg(\int_{\mathbb R^d}|g| dx\bigg) < \infty
$$
this follows easily with Fubini. Now assume $lim_{|x| \rightarrow \infty}f*g \space(x)  \neq 0$ and your left hand side would be an unbounded integral.

Comment: An integrable function doesn't tend, necessarily, to zero. But the idea is good.

Comment: I don't know why the left side is unbounded. can you explain more detail?

Comment: @user90189 that is true, but isnt it true for the absolute value for the function?

Comment: Define in $\mathbb{R}$ the function $\sum_{N} \chi_{[-1/2^N,1/2^{N}]}(x-N)$ for integers $N\ge 0$.

Comment: To complete your argument, I would try to use the fact that convolution of summable function is continuous, and that it is almost constant over balls of a fixed size.

Comment: That sounds good. I will edit later

Comment: Ranc already completed the argument :)